# Uncaught OAuthException error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

A few days ago my app was working fine. Now I'm getting this error after the user tries to authenticate it:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#1) An unknown error occurred thrown in /home/.../public_html/..../src/base_facebook.php on line 1024
```

all of a sudden i am seeing this and traffic is falling a lot because people can't use the app.

Comment: This site is not about magic, if you want help you need to provide some info regarding your problem, like at which stage of the authentication this error occurs? What's in the mysterious "base_facebook.php"? Is it the official SDK? We can't just magically know what's wrong with your app you know.

Answer (score 1):

use try {} catch block, example :

```
 try {   
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {       
      die($e->getMessage());
 }
```

Then you can find out how to catch it... and you can provide us more info